# Binding interface per core

Tags: linux, ethernet, multi-core

I just wonder, is it possible (using Linux 2.6) to limit overhead done by ethernet interface to one specific core.
Ie. I have core2duo CPU, and two ethernet interfaces: eth0 and eth1.
Is it possible to move system load caused by packets comming on eth0 to CPU0, so the other core (CPU1) will be idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You probably don't want to do this](http://www.alexonlinux.com/smp-affinity-and-proper-interrupt-handling-in-linux), even if it is possible (which I'm sure it is, I haven't read the full article in the link).

Comment: I have came across with this, but I don't believe it cover subject completly.
It is just interrupt handling, not the overhead itself (packet needs to be parsed by kernel,iptables, and so on). Am i correct? 
What I want is to separate EVERY aspect of ethernet connection, not only the fact of creating connection.

Comment: @user90960: Up to what level? In the end, do you want to restrict FireFox to CPU0 if-and-only-if it's rendering a webpage that was retrieved via eth0? IOW, can you clarify what you *really* want? What tangible benefit are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe 3rd OSI level will be sufficient, but I get your point.